# PyQt - Custom scrolling with QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qscrollbar

I am trying to figure out a way to customize the scrollbars for `QListWidget` to have the scrollbars above and below the `QListWidget` instead of the normal vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

Please check out my example below if you don't understand what I mean.
In the example below I use `QPushButtons` with `QTimers` controlling the scrolling in place of the scrollbars but what I am looking for are scrollbars like the ones in `QMenu` when menu scrolling is enabled.

If that is not an option, I am wondering if there is a scrollbar signal or something that I could try to use to know when the scrollbars are normally activated? That way I can show/hide the buttons as needed. Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QStyle, QListWidget, QStyleOptionButton, QListWidgetItem

class UpBtn(QPushButton):
    mouseHover = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.timer = QTimer()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        opt = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        self.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ScrollBarSubLine, opt, painter, self)
        painter.end()

    def startScroll(self):
        self.mouseHover.emit()

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.startScroll)
        self.timer.start(120)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()

class DwnBtn(QPushButton):
    mouseHover = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.timer = QTimer()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        opt = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        self.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ScrollBarAddLine, opt, painter, self)
        painter.end()

    def startScroll(self):
        self.mouseHover.emit()

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.startScroll)
        self.timer.start(120)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.upBtn = UpBtn()
        self.upBtn.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.upBtn)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.downBtn = DwnBtn()
        self.downBtn.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.downBtn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.upBtn.clicked.connect(self.upBtnClicked)
        self.upBtn.mouseHover.connect(self.upBtnClicked)
        self.downBtn.clicked.connect(self.downBtnClicked)
        self.downBtn.mouseHover.connect(self.downBtnClicked)

        for i in range(100):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText("list item " + str(i))
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def upBtnClicked(self):
        cur = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(cur - 1)

    def downBtnClicked(self):
        cur = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(cur + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: 
Here is an example image for what I am talking about. This is a scrollable `QMenu`.

[image]

EDIT:
Scrollable `QMenu` code.
Uncomment the commented parts to get a fixed size like in the image. Normally Qmenu scrolling only works when the menu items exceed the screen height. I am just looking for the top and bottom hover style scrolling but to be used in `QListWidget`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QAction, QMenu, QProxyStyle, QStyle

class MyMenu(QMenu):
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Show:
            self.move(self.parent().mapToGlobal(QPoint(-108, 0)))
        return super(MyMenu, self).event(event)

# class CustomStyle(QProxyStyle):
#     def pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option=None, widget=None):
#         if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_MenuScrollerHeight:
#             return 15
#         if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_MenuDesktopFrameWidth:
#             return 290
#         else:
#             return QProxyStyle.pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option, widget)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.btn.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.myMenu = MyMenu("Menu", self.btn)
        self.btn.setMenu(self.myMenu)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        menus = []
        for _ in range(5):
            myMenus = QMenu("Menu"+str(_+1), self.btn)
            # myMenus.setFixedHeight(120)
            myMenus.setStyleSheet("QMenu{menu-scrollable: 1; }")
            menus.append(myMenus)
        for i in menus:
            self.btn.menu().addMenu(i)
            for item in range(100):
                action = QAction("item" + str(item), self)
                i.addAction(action)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # app.setStyle(CustomStyle())
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get. When do you want the buttons to be displayed? If I execute your code, just look at the scroll if the mouse is over the buttons, I have no idea what you want to get.

Comment: I am pretty much trying to get the same functionality or close to how the scrolling works in QMenu if possible. If I have to use buttons like in my example I would like the buttons to only show as needed like scrollbars normally do when the list is long and items go out of view. When the list is short and fully in view in the listwidget I would like to hide the buttons which is why I am looking for either a built in method for using scrollbars or try to capture when the scrollbars are normally activated so I know when to show/hide the buttons.

Comment: The QMenu are dependent on the style and the OS, so I do not understand what you want to obtain, you could show an image of the QMenu that you mean to understand you better. On the other hand, the second point I already understand.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I just updated my post with an image.

Comment: One last thing, you could share the scrollable QMenu code

Comment: Just updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to obtain the row of the upper and lower element that will decide whether the buttons are hidden or not, for that we use the method itemAt () that returns the item given the geometrical coordinates. On the other hand I have improved this calculation has to do every time they change the number of items in the QListView for that we use the signals of the internal model.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    moveSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=120)
        self.m_timer.timeout.connect(self.moveSignal)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setFixedHeight(20)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super(Button, self).mousePressEvent(e)
        self.setDown(True)

    def enterEvent(self, e):
        self.setDown(True)
        self.m_timer.start()
        super(Button, self).enterEvent(e)

    def leaveEvent(self, e):
        self.setDown(False)
        self.m_timer.stop()
        super(Button, self).leaveEvent(e)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(230)

        icon = self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowUp)
        self.upBtn = Button(icon=icon)
        self.upBtn.moveSignal.connect(self.moveUp)
        icon = self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowDown)
        self.downBtn = Button(icon=icon)
        self.downBtn.moveSignal.connect(self.moveDown)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(self.upBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.downBtn)
        self.adjust_buttons()
        self.create_connections()

    def create_connections(self):
        self.listWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.adjust_buttons)
        model = self.listWidget.model()
        model.rowsInserted.connect(self.adjust_buttons)
        model.rowsRemoved.connect(self.adjust_buttons)
        model.rowsMoved.connect(self.adjust_buttons)
        model.modelReset.connect(self.adjust_buttons)
        model.layoutChanged.connect(self.adjust_buttons)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def adjust_buttons(self):
        first = self.listWidget.itemAt(QtCore.QPoint())
        r = self.listWidget.row(first)
        self.upBtn.setVisible(r != 0 and  r!= -1)
        last = self.listWidget.itemAt(self.listWidget.viewport().rect().bottomRight())
        r = self.listWidget.row(last)
        self.downBtn.setVisible( r != (self.listWidget.count() -1) and r != -1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def moveUp(self):
        ix = self.listWidget.moveCursor(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MoveUp, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def moveDown(self):
        ix = self.listWidget.moveCursor(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MoveDown, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_item(self, text):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(text)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    for i in range(100):
        window.add_item("item {}".format(i))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It seems to work great, thanks a lot man, very much appreciated!

Comment: @Richard you see if you provide information such as images or code that allows us to understand your requirement is more likely to find a solution. :-)

Comment: Yeah I know, I thought I was pretty clear at first with the code but then I remembered QMenus are platform dependent after you mentioned it so I understand now why my question was a bit difficult to answer without more information.